# QSortFilterProxyModel: progress of filtering

Tags: c++, qt

I have table that contains a lot of rows and I filter it with QSortFilterProxyModel, but process of filtering takes long time. I'd like to visualize progress of filtering by progress bar, but I can't find out how many rows have been filtered at that moment.

Comment: If you override the `filterAcceptsRow` function, you could create a counter that gets incremented every time that function gets called.

Comment: But filterAccepsRow is const method, so it's impossible to increment some field

Comment: Ah, good point. I missed that.

Comment: You can have [`mutable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv#mutable_specifier) class members.  Having said that I suspect the real difficulty will be deciding when a model wide filter operation begins and ends.